# What instance, example or experiment contradicts Maxwell's (abandoned) model of magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, history

In "On Physical Lines of Force", Maxwell uses rotating cells as a model of magnetism. He and others abandoned this model of magnetism. Given our current knowledge of magnetism and related phenomenons, what instance, example or experiment contradicts Maxwell's model of magnetism? In other words, which observation or effect could we point to show that this model is completely wrong (or mostly wrong)?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the model? Do you mean something like an array of rotating current rings?

Comment: @YardenSheffer The model is that of a new kind of particles existing in a vacuum (cells). When current flows, the current rubs against these cells causing them to rotate, when they rotate they expand, causing a repulsion. This explains why two wires hanging next to each other wirh current going in the opposite direction repell, becuase both currents constructively contribute to rotation between them causing the cells to expand.

Comment: It isn’t really a physical theory until you write down the governing equations. It would be possible, I suppose, to develop a theory based on “cells” which is mathematically equivalent to Maxwell’s Equations, in which case it could not be refuted on the basis of classical electrodynamics alone. So if you provide the governing equations, we might determine whether the theory fails within that domain or whether one needs to appeal to atomic/solid state/more fundamental physics to argue that rotating cells don’t exist, atoms do.